# Add test that checks all files are formatted correctly to Karma \ Travis

Tags: javascript, testing, formatting, karma-runner, travis-ci

I'm implementing some tests for a project of mine using karma locally, and Travis for **github** tests integration (you can't merge pull requests unless all tests pass)

I really want to do the same for code formatting.
I'm using **jscs** with **gulp** in order to lint the code.

I thought about adding a test for **Travis** in order to make tests fail if a PR isn't formatted correctly.

Is there a standard way of doing this?
Currently, I thought about two options: adding a test to my test suit that checks formatting. make the test fail if any error returned. The other option, is to just run a task on **Travis**, but I can't make the **Travis** build fail on the lint task.

I saw there's a preprocessor for karma but as much as I was able to check, it doesn't make travis fail if any jscs errors were found.

**Is there any better practice for this?**

I couldn't find anything on the internet since `<TEST_FRAMEWORK> test file formatting` just returns a lot of results about how to correctly format your tests (readability)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it looks like there isn't any standard way of doing this, I will list two options of doing something like this:

## Before everything

You need to make you gulp/grunt task return a **non-zero** in order for it to fail. If a task fails, **Travis** will take that as a build failure, which will indicate that tests failed for the PR.
In **gulp** and **jscs**, I did it like so:

```
gulp.task('lint-js', function() {
  return gulp.src(FILES.JS_ALL)
      .pipe(cache('linting'))
      .pipe(jscs())
      .pipe(jscs.reporter())
      .pipe(jscs.reporter('fail'));
});
```

Most linters have a reporter. If you pipe a `.reporter('fail')` at the end, it will return a **non-zero** if your linter returned any lint errors.

For **Grunt**, by **@Nocomm** answer, it looks like grunt automatically returns a **non-zero** if any lint errors were found.

## 1) Making you test task fail if files aren't formatted

you can just add your `lint` task as a dependecy for you `test` task. If you add it like so:

```
gulp.task('test', ['lint-js'], function() {//...
```

When **Travis** will start running your tests, it will first check that all files are formatted correctly. If they're not, **Travis** will take the **non-zero** return as a failure and report correctly on **GitHub**

## 2) Adding your gulp lint task to Travis's before_script

Now that your lint task fails on lint warnings, your can add that task to `.travis.yml` `before_script` list of commands to run before running tests.
Just add it to the end of the list in order to run it just before tests (why run tests on a PR that is going to fail because of formatting?), and right after you install everything needed to run such a task.

From the **Travis** log files:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to run all of my JavaScript tasks.  They both do the same things, but are very different in the way they look and feel.  I am not an expert at either of them, so take what I say with a grain of salt.  I don't have experience with Travis, but I currently use Grunt in one of my Jenkins builds.

I am assuming you are familiar with NodeJS and npm if you are using Karma.

**I'll give you an example using Grunt to illustrate what I think you are trying to do.**

1. In order to use Grunt anywhere, you will need to install it globally: `npm install -g grunt-cli`.
2. In order to use Grunt with Karma, you will need to install `grunt-karma`.  In your project's root: `npm install --save-dev grunt-karma`.  This example won't include karma configuration since you can do what you want to without it.
3. To lint the project's files you are currently using jscs. There is a Grunt plugin for this too: [grunt-jscs](https://github.com/jscs-dev/grunt-jscs).  However, I am familiar with jshint, so that is what I will use in this example. In your project's root: `npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-jshint`.

Now here is an example `Gruntfile.js`, which should also be located in your project's root.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    // Task configuration.
    jshint: {
      options: {
        devel: true,
        curly: true,
        eqeqeq: false,
        immed: true,
        latedef: false,
        newcap: true,
        noarg: true,
        sub: true,
        undef: true,
        unused: true,
        boss: true,
        eqnull: true,
        browser: true,
        globals: {
          jQuery: true,
          angular: true
        }
      },
      gruntfile: {
        src: 'Gruntfile.js'
      },
      lib_test: {
        src: ['src/app/**/*.js', '!src/app/libs/**/*.js']
      }
    }
  });

  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint']);
};
```

To run the task from the command line, go to the directory where your `Gruntfile.js` is and run `grunt test`.  I'm not sure if this is application to Travis, but in Jenkins the build fails if JSHint finds errors. This can be bypassed if you use the `--force` option: `grunt --force test`.

`lib_test` under the jshint task configuration includes the files you want to lint.  Make sure they are relative to where your Gruntfile lives, which should be in the project's root.

Grunt and Gulp can do so much more.  If you really want to get into JavaScript task automation, I would suggest learning Gulp. However, I think this should be a good short-term solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use gulp already. It wasn't a question about how to lint my JavaScript. It was about if there's any standard way to integrate such a test with Travis. Which is a continues integration system to run tests for github.